# Selecting distinct count in a group with only null values for a specific column

Tags: mysql, sql, hiveql

I have 2 columns like this - id and val.

[image]

I require such distinct id's where corresponding to each id there is a null value present.
Is it plausible to use "group by" by id and then use "having" clause where null is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `NOT EXISTS` :

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id)
FROM table t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table t1 WHERE t1.id = t.id AND t1.val IS NOT NULL);
```

Other option uses the `GROUP BY` :

```
SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM table t
GROUP BY id
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN val IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

Comment: The middle table in the picture is the output of "group by". It's not a separate table.

Comment: @nOObda. . . This query will give you third part & here i am considered only 1 table.

Comment: Yeah got it. But can NULL be used with having.
Like - Having val == NULL

Comment: @nOObda. . . Yes, you can but the `LOGIC` would be conditional.

Comment: Thanks for the help and suggestions Sir.

Answer (score 1):

To get ids that have a `NULL` value, I would be inclined to start with this:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having count(*) <> count(val);
```

This structure allows you to check for other values, such as a non-`NULL` value.

The simplest method to get the distinct ids with `NULL` values is:

```
select distinct id
from t
where val is null;
```

If you only want the count:

```
select count(distinct id)
from t
where val is null;
```

Comment: I think the first one corresponds to the question. Cos if we "group" by id's then only those groups are to be selected where all values are null for column "val". Like 2 null, 3 null , 3 null. Thus getting a distinct count of 2 for such groups.

Comment: @nOObda . . . I have explained the logic for the three queries.  I definitely think the last is the simplest solution to your specific question.

Comment: Thanks for the help Sir.